# what is the significance of /usr/local/lib/dtrace directory in macOS?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra, installation-package, installation-path

When trying to remove node modules while uninstalling nodejs, I deleted the whole /usr/local/lib/dtrace directory. How do I recover contents of dtrace directory?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the significance of the `/usr/local/lib/dtrace` directory, but mine has the permissions 755 (`rwxr-xr-x`) and only contains one text file named `node.d` with the permissions 644 (`-rw-r--r--`).

The comments at the top of that file say:

> ```
> * This is the DTrace library file for the node provider, which includes
> * the necessary translators to get from the args[] to something useful.
> ```

You can download a copy of the `node.d` file [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node.d).